# SQLite Insufficient parameters supplied to the command

Tags: c#, sqlite, prepared-statement

By adding a parameter to the query, the error raised on the `DB.Fill(DS)` line.
The parameter `@id` is exactly equal to the parameter of the query.
I've search a lot but all solution is about typo of parameter name.

```
SQLiteDataAdapter DB;      
DataSet DS = new DataSet();
DataTable DT = new DataTable();

SetConnection();
sqlCmd = sqlCon.CreateCommand();
string CommandText = "select * from Words where id = @id"; //query;
await sqlCon.OpenAsync();

sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1);
DB = new SQLiteDataAdapter(CommandText, sqlCon);

DS.Reset();
await Task.Run(() => { DB.Fill(DS); });
DT = DS.Tables[0];
sqlCon.Close();
return DT;
```

**UPDATE = Solution**
As @steve16351 said, the problem is with CommandText.
Just add the query to sqlCmd and send it as SQLiteDataAdapter parameter.

```
sqlCmd = sqlCon.CreateCommand();
sqlCmd.CommandText("select * from Words where id = @id"); //query; <<==  
await sqlCon.OpenAsync();
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1);
DB = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sqlCmd); <<==
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using the SQL command that you've added the parameter to, you're passing the `SQLiteDataAdapter` the command text directly. Use the overload that takes the command object:

```
sqlCmd.CommandText = "select * from Words where id = @id"; //query;
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1);
DB = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
```

And here is a more complete example:

```
using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=c:\temp\mydbthatdoesnotexistyet.db;Version=3;"))
{
    conn.Open();

    // create the words table
    var create = conn.CreateCommand();
    create.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE Words (Id INT, Word TEXT)";
    create.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // insert data to the table
    var populate = conn.CreateCommand();
    populate.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Words (Id, Word) VALUES (@Id, @Word)";
    populate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", 1);
    populate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Word", "abc");
    populate.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // select the data back from the table
    var select = conn.CreateCommand();
    select.CommandText = "SELECT Word FROM Words WHERE Id = @Id";
    select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", 1);

    SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(select);
    DataSet data = new DataSet();
    dataAdapter.Fill(data);
    DataTable table = data.Tables[0];
}
```

Comment: this error raised: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
even I have added this line: sqlCmd = new SQLiteCommand();

Comment: I've added a complete, working minimal example, perhaps that will help you see where the problem is. Alternatively, add your new code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Like is used for text comparison. You just need a match or not, thus:

```
string CommandText = "select * from Words where id = @id";
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but it's not the answer. It raises the error again.

Answer (score 0):

Like :

```
   string CommandText = "select * from Words where id = $id"; //query;
```

after :

```
   sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$id", 1);
```